# Django: how to access JsonResponse dictionary in jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, django

Jquery

```
$('#id_buysell').on('change', function(){

            console.log("buysell");

            var $id_buysell = $('#id_buysell').val();
            console.log($id_buysell);

            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "/myportfolio/add_transaction",
                data: { buysell: $id_buysell }
            });

        });
```

Views

```
def add_transaction(request):

    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.is_ajax():
            print("ajax test")

            #print(request.GET.get)
            print(request.GET.get('coin'))
            print(request.GET.get('buysell'))


            data = {
                'view_buysell': request.GET.get('buysell'),
                'view_coin': request.GET.get('coin')
            }

            form = TransactionForm(user = request.user, coin_price = GetCoin("Bitcoin").price)

            return JsonResponse(data)
```

How do I access that dictionary sent from JsonResponse(data) in views to my jquery file? I have a limited understanding of jquery and front end development in general. I know that this will be sent through a JSON-encoded response, but have not been able to find the right answer when searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You perform an AJAX request with `$.ajax(..)`, but you never specify what to do in case the request succeeds, and how you should handle the data.

The object you pass to the the `$.ajax(..)` call, can contain a `success` key, that should contain a function that is called with the response:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/myportfolio/add_transaction",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, status) {
        // do something with data and status
    },
    data: { buysell: $id_buysell }
});
```

`data` thus contains the data wrapped in the response, and `status` the status code of the response.

You can add an `error` key as well: a function that is called in case the response returns an error:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/myportfolio/add_transaction",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, status) {
        // do something with data and status
    },
    error: function(response) {
        // do something in case the request returns an error
        // for example alert the user that the buy/sell transaction failed
        // (by checking response.status, response.responseText, etc.)
    },
    data: { buysell: $id_buysell }
});
```